# JavaDoc based on annotations

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc, uima

I have a class that contains annotations on class-level variables. In my specific case, it's uimaFIT annotations denoting configuration parameters, but for the sake of simplicity let's assume the following:

```
public class MyClass{
  @MyParameter(key="Foo", description="Example parameter")
  private String myVariable;

  //...rest of the class here
}
```

In my JavaDoc, I would like to be able to extract variables marked with the *@MyParameter* and have the key and description listed on the class page. (The reason being that the values of these parameters can be injected by the user, and given I've already written a description for them in the annotations it seems pointless separately writing documentation.)

The output might look like the following, although just getting it in there at all would be a start!:

> **Foo** - *Example Parameter*

Is this possible? I don't mind writing my own classes to 'extend' the JavaDoc if required, but could do with someone pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for doclets https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html
They allow you to extend JavaDoc functionality.
You can write your own doclet and use reflection api to gather your annotations data.

Answer (score 1):

uimaFIT has a solution for this. Instead of extracting information from the uimaFIT annotation and putting it into JavaDoc, uimaFIT can extract information from the JavaDoc and put it into its description. So here is what you do:

- Do not use a literal for the key, but use a constant that starts with PARAM_
- Write regular JavaDoc on that constant instead of using the description parameter.

```
/**
 * Enable or disable my feature.
 */
public static final String PARAM_ENABLE_FEATURE = "enableFeature";
@ConfigurationParameter(name=PARAM_ENABLE_FEATURE)
private boolean enableFeature;
```

Now, use the uimafit-maven-plugin to automatically fill the description in from the JavaDoc:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
        <artifactId>uimafit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

For more information, please refer to the [uimaFIT documentation](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#tools.uimafit.maven).

*Disclosure: I am working on uimaFIT.*

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc `.html` files are created by the [`javadoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/) tool.  You can plug in [doclets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html) to customize the output of `javadoc`.

If you need to write your own Javadoc plugin, it's best to start from existing code rather than from scratch.

One Javadoc plugin that reads annotations and adds the result to the Javadoc output is for plume-lib's [Options](http://types.cs.washington.edu/plume-lib/api/plume/Options.html) annotation.  If a program uses the `@Option` annotation, its Javadoc contains a description of its command-line options.  Here are [two](http://randoop.googlecode.com/hg/doc/index.html#command-line-options) [examples](http://types.cs.washington.edu/javari/javarifier/#command-line-opts).  The advantage is that you only have to write the documentation once; the source code, manual, and usage messages always stay in sync.

You can find the [OptionsDoclet source code](http://plume-lib.googlecode.com/hg/java/src/plume/Options.java) in the [plume-lib repository](https://plume-lib.googlecode.com/).  You will want to customize it to produce output of the form you want.